# Declare local variables oracle toad

Tags: sql, oracle, declaration

How can I write a basic query, which declare variables and print those variables in a select statement.

I tried assign values to variables and it ran successfully. But when I print it, that didn’t show in the out put. I tried below block:

```
declare
    debit_at varchar(100); 
begin
    select ac in to Debit_at
    from table1 where ac = ‘123’;

    dbms_output.put_line(Debit_at);
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query is absolutely right. Just  there is a typo in your query. instead of `in to` it will be `into`

```
Declare Debit_at varchar(100);

Begin 
Select ac Into Debit_at from table1 where ac = ‘123’;

Dbms_output.put_line(Debit_at);

End;
```

Answer (score 2):

> But when I print it, that didn’t show in the out put.

If you don't see the output, you have to **enable** it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use VARCHAR2 because that case you set up the longness by byte not by character.

Declare
Debit_at varchar2(100) // If you like set up the value := 'your value';

Begin

Select ac Into Debit_at from table1 where ac = ‘123’;

Dbms_output.put_line(Debit_at);

End;

Comment: "you can use VARCHAR2 because that case you set up the longness by byte not by character" - are you sure? You can specify length in bytes and characters for both VARCHAR and VARCHAR2 datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

The Block seems to be correct, make sure you enable the DBMS output and execute it as script. And also you must have some data to output, i.e.

`SELECT * FORM TABLE1 WHERE AC = '123'; -- has some data to output, it should not be NULL.`